# Правда ли, что глагол "запикать" приобрёл новое значение с развитием телевидения в России и странах ближнего зарубежья после распада СССР в 90-х?

Tags: этимология, глаголы

В русском языке глагол "запикать" в последнее время часто употребляют в значении "скрыть нежелательные слова в аудио или видеозаписях при помощи звука писка, чаще всего нецензурные". Хотя ещё в советские времена глагол "запикать" имел совсем иное значение "начать пикать (издавать короткий писк)". Так почему данный глагол в настоящее время употребляют в основном для обозначения маскировки нецензурной брани при помощи звукового сигнала на телевидении, радио и даже в Интернете? Не стоит забывать о том, что во многих странах мира, включая Россию, США, существуют законы, которые запрещают или ограничивают использование нецензурных слов и выражений в теле- и радиоэфире, а также в интернет-СМИ. К такой маскировке нецензурной брани в последние годы всё чаще прибегают на телевидении и радио в России и странах ближнего зарубежья, прежде всего из-за распространенности нецензурной брани в речи россиян и жителей стран постсоветского пространства: нецензурная брань часто встречается в видеороликах, которые показывают в новостях и публикуют в Интернете. Такое очень часто встречается в новостных программах, ток-шоу, реалити-шоу и т.п. То же самое и в других странах мира. Стоит также отметить, что в английском языке уже давно есть термин "bleep censor", которым называют маскировку нецензурной брани при помощи специального звукового сигнала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правда. Глагол "запикать" в последнее время часто употребляют в значении "скрыть нежелательные слова в аудио- или видеозаписях при помощи звука писка".
Раньше такую технологию не использовали, поэтому, когда она появилась, у слова "запикать" и появилось новое значение.

Comment: В России и странах постсоветского пространства такую технологию запикивания нецензурной лексики действительно стали применять ещё в начале 90-х годов, ещё задолго до того, как запрет на нецензурную брань был введён на законодательном уровне в России и некоторых странах ближнего зарубежья. Такая необходимость остро назрела в связи с изменениями ситуации в обществе в России и на постсоветском пространстве после распада СССР, когда использование нецензурной брани стало возрастать. Однако американцы начали применять такую технологию цензурирования слов ещё в начале 1920-х годов.

Comment: @МаркИз Извините, Господин Модератор, подправила. С наступающим Новым годом! Всех благ!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова извиняться не стоит, я очень даже рад, что в сообществе есть те, кто готовы подправить неточности пользователей. Вас также с наступающим.